# Exclusions to RD command in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm using the below script to clear a set of folders after certain tasks are completed.

```
@echo off
setlocal
:PROMPT
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Clearing folder! Are you sure? (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END

echo

cd /d "P:\folder1\"
rd /s /q . 2>nul
cd /d "P:\folder2\"
rd /s /q . 2>nul
cd /d "P:\folder3\"
rd /s /q . 2>nul

:END
endlocal
```

The issue is that there are identifier files and subdirectories within `folder1`, `folder2`, etc. that need to stay there.

So for instance, there is a directory with the path of `P:\folder1\.identifiersubfolder` and a file in `folder1` named `P:\folder1\identifier.file`

These have a set file and directory name, so I do not need wildcards. I need a way to simply set a file and directory name to exclude. I can't figure out if rd/rmdir can do that. If there is another command I can use, I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: You  need a `for` loop with conditional `IF NOT` logic to omit the directories you need to exclude from the rd commands. Not enough time right now to do this for you, but for command line batch, that may be worth exploring with google, etc. Otherwise, the PowerShell `get-childitem` has an `-exclude` switch for this purpose too.

Comment: I'm open to using PowerShell. I'll explore both options, but if PS has an exclude switch, I'll probably just go that route. Thanks for the suggestion!.

Comment: If you want to stick to the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Command-Line PreProcessor, then you can play some nice Monkey Tricks. The `RMDIR` Operating System Command does not play them. Try moving the Folders and the Files out there, outside of their original location; remove everything blindly; then move them back. For instance: `XCOPY /E P:\Folder1\.IdentifierSubFolder P:\ `; `RMDIR /S /Q . 2>NUL`; `XCOPY /E P:\.IdentifierSubFolder P:\Folder1\ `.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai That's a good suggestion. I just want to clarify. Are you saying there's no direct way to set a switch for `RMDIR`? If that's the case, I'll probably go with PS. Your suggestion would work, however, I'm not sure how my programs would like the files being moved. I would have to test it. Something to keep in mind for sure though.

Comment: The `RMDIR` Operating System Command is pretty dumb. It has only the `/S` and the `/Q` Switches. Yes, you have understood it right. There is _no_ way to set any kind of Supplemental Switch for it. We have created a nice Supplemental Answer for your Issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using `Remove-Item –path P:\Testing\folder1\ -Recurse` in PowerShell, and calling this via my old batch file, in place of `rd`.

I simply set the items I want excluded as hidden, and did not use `-Force` in the PS script to block it from removing those items. Without using `-Force`, the script doesn't have access to remove hidden items. My programs make these files hidden by default, so it works out in this situation.

Thanks for the suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Batch Solution for your Issue.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal
:Prompt
Set /P AreYouSure=Clearing Folder! Are you sure? (Y/[N])?
If /I "%AreYouSure%" NEq "Y" GoTo End

Echo

ChDir /D "P:\Folder1\"
XCopy /E P:\Folder1\.IdentifierSubFolder\ P:\
Copy /Y P:\Folder1\Identifier.File P:\
RmDir /S /Q . 2>Nul
XCopy /E P:\.IdentifierSubFolder\ P:\Folder1\
RmDir /S /Q P:\.IdentifierSubFolder\
Copy /Y P:\Identifier.File P:\Folder1\
Erase /Q P:\Identifier.File

ChDir /D "P:\Folder2\"
XCopy /E P:\Folder2\.IdentifierSubFolder\ P:\
Copy /Y P:\Folder2\Identifier.File P:\
RmDir /S /Q . 2>Nul
XCopy /E P:\.IdentifierSubFolder\ P:\Folder2\
RmDir /S /Q P:\.IdentifierSubFolder\
Copy /Y P:\Identifier.File P:\Folder2\
Erase /Q P:\Identifier.File

ChDir /D "P:\Folder3\"
XCopy /E P:\Folder3\.IdentifierSubFolder\ P:\
Copy /Y P:\Folder3\Identifier.File P:\
RmDir /S /Q . 2>Nul
XCopy /E P:\.IdentifierSubFolder\ P:\Folder3\
RmDir /S /Q P:\.IdentifierSubFolder\
Copy /Y P:\Identifier.File P:\Folder3\
Erase /Q P:\Identifier.File

:End
EndLocal
```